# Track activity or event on email by using Facebook pixel

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-pixel

How can we track an activity or an event on email and add custom audience by using Facebook pixel tracking?

Answer (score 0):

You can not track whole activity but still you can track PageView event of mail using Facebook Pixel.

From your pixel code, use image tag within `<noscript>` tag and use it in mail as `<image>` tag.

```html
<img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
  src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1234567890&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/>
```

So this will fire PageView everytime user opens mail.